# C# - Is it possible to call any member functions of List through read-only wrapper?

Tags: c#, list, readonly

I have the following function 'Foo':

```
int Foo(List<int> list, int value) {
  int i1 = list.IndexOf(value);
  int i2 = list.LastIndexOf(value);
  return i2 - i1;
}
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(Foo(list,1)); // 4
```

'Foo' calls [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.lastindexof?view=net-6.0) method of [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) and does not modify the 'list' parameter.

Now I want `Foo(list.AsReadOnly(),1)` instead of `Foo(list,1)` to explicitly show that the list will not be modified.

However, if I replace [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) parameter type with [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-6.0)(Or  IReadOnlyList, ReadOnlyCollection, etc.) for receiving the read-only wrapper, the LastIndexOf method won't work.

```
int Bar(IList<int> list, int value) {
  int i1 = list.IndexOf(value);
  int i2 = list.LastIndexOf(value); // Method doesn't exist!
  return i2 - i1;
}
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(Bar(list.AsReadOnly(),1));
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: It's not, see this discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34020; you could write an extension method to achieve it.

Comment: Unfortunately, LastIndexOf is a method of List<T>. One option is to use IEnumerable and either write your own LastIndexOf method or create a local instance of List<T> from it.